# .xsession exec not recognise $HOME or arguments?

Tags: session, xmonad, lightdm, x

The basic scenario is that I'm sharing my dot files across multiple machines and want to have my session definitons synced as well.

Since I use different laptops and monitors with significantly different DPIs I want to be able to manually specify the desired DPI  for each session.

After a few ugly(`s/y/ier/g`) hacks I settled on the .xsession running a wrapper script instead of directly calling `xmonad-start` (or `gnome-session` or whatever), and passing the desired DPI to that wrapper script. Like so:

#### /usr/share/.xsessions/xmonad-standard.xsession

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xmonad
Exec=/home/itsamemario/.xmonad/xmonad-start
```

#### /usr/share/.xsessions/xmonad-hidpi.xsession

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xmonad HiDPI
Exec=/home/itsamemario/.xmonad/xmonad-start 192
```

#### /home/itsamemario/.xmonad/xmonad-start

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb -merge "$HOME/.Xresources"

# For setting DPI by passing an argument from display manager
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
  TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
  echo "! Fonts {{{
Xft.dpi: $1
! }}}" > "$TMPFILE"
  xrdb -merge "$TMPFILE"
  notify-send "Setting DPI to $1"
  rm -f "$TMPFILE"
fi

# Other unimportant stuff here

exec /usr/bin/xmonad
```

Everything works great on two installs, but on the third one I can't run any session except the default one with no arguments passed. I just get the following error in .xsession-errors and it drops back to lightdm:

```
/etc/lightdm/Xsession: line 76: /home/itsamemario/.xmonad/xmonad-start 192: No such file or directory
```

In the course of debugging I've also noticed that I can also normally use `$HOME/.xmonad/xmonad-start` and `.xmonad/xmonad-start` on the other two installs but on this one it only works if I explicitly include `/home/itsamemario/`. All three are running Arch and I can't see any relevant difference in how they were installed or configured.

What could be causing `exec` lines in .xsessions to not pass arguments properly, and possibly also not expand session variables like `$HOME`?

(I know there are better workarounds to the DPI issue but my wrapper script approach addresses other requirements. I'm just focusing on DPI only here for the sake of simplicity.)

Comment: Maybe using bash and it's debug + error mode - `set -x` and `set -e` might be a way to further diagnose this.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-custom.html.en

On Debian change the following in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/20x11-common_process-args`

> Change `STARTUP_FULL_PATH=$(/usr/bin/which "$1"|| true)` to `STARTUP_FULL_PATH=$(/usr/bin/which $1 || true)`
>
> Change `STARTUP="$1"` to `STARTUP=$1`